# Pod install not working on Mac M1 Pro chip

Tags: react-native, installation, apple-m1, silicon

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /Users/hirenchheta/Desktop/ErgoAuditor_repo/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.

### from /Users/hirenchheta/Desktop/ErgoAuditor_repo/ios/Podfile:1

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

Answer (score 0):

Mac M1 architecture is not directly compatible with Cocoapods.
You can solve it by running:

```
       sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi


       arch -x86_64 pod install
```

[https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#:~:text=Note%20for%20Mac,the%20proper%20architecture](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#:%7E:text=Note%20for%20Mac,the%20proper%20architecture).